# how to hide a modal when cancel button pressed in bootstrapvalidation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, bootstrap-modal

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$("#login-link").on("click", function() { 
$("#login-modal").modal("show");

});

$('#loginform')
    .bootstrapValidator({
    excluded: ':disabled',
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        username: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The username is required'
                }
            }
        },
        password: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The password is required'
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
    .on('success.form.bv', function (e) {
    // Prevent form submission
    e.preventDefault();


      // Get the form instance
        var $form = $(e.target);

        // Get the BootstrapValidator instance
        var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');

        // Use Ajax to submit form data
        $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(result) {

          if(result=="success")
          {
            window.location = "home.php";
          }
          else
          {
            alert("wrong username or password");
          }
        }, 'json');



    $('#login-modal').modal('hide');
});

$('#login-modal')
   .on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
       $('#loginform').find('[name="username"]').focus();
    })
    .on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#loginform').bootstrapValidator('resetForm', true);
    });
    });
```

This is part of my code. here how to close the modal when cancel button is pressed in bootstrapvalidation plugin and how to clear the formfild values in bootstrapvalidation plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not shure if that is what you are looking for but anywhay I would recomend to go on the bootstrap site 
http://getbootstrap.com/css/

there you will find a cross delete button:

```
<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
```

and this close button, might be what you were looking for:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

Comment: thats ok.this i knew it. what i want is..i have 2 buttons in a form within modal and when i press cancel the model should be closed and when i press submit the form should be submitted and if it contains any error it should validate. but now if i press cancel also the validation is working but instead of this the modal should be closed

Comment: could you than please submit my answer:)

Comment: <button class="btn btn-default" id="cancel-button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>